# Unexpected result in pandas pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, pivot-table

I am trying to do a pivot_table on a pandas Dataframe. I am *almost* getting the expected result, but it seems to be multiplied by two. I could just divide by two and call it a day, however, I want to know whether I am doing something wrong.

Here goes the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"IND":[1,2,3,4,5,1,5,5],"DATA":[2,3,4,2,10,4,3,3]})
df_pvt = pd.pivot_table(df, aggfunc=np.size, index=["IND"], columns="DATA")
```

`df_pvt` is now:

```
DATA   2    3    4    10
IND                     
1     2.0  NaN  2.0  NaN
2     NaN  2.0  NaN  NaN
3     NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN
4     2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
5     NaN  4.0  NaN  2.0
```

However, instead of the 2.0 is should be 1.0! What am I misunderstanding / doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the string `'size'` instead. This will trigger the Pandas interpretation of "size", i.e. the number of elements in a group. The NumPy interpretation of size is the product of the lengths of each dimension.

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df, aggfunc='size', index=["IND"], columns="DATA")

print(df)

DATA   2    3    4    10
IND                     
1     1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN
2     NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
3     NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN
4     1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
5     NaN  2.0  NaN  1.0
```

Comment: Thank you. This is giving the expected result. Do you know why np.size is giving the wrong result? According to the documentation, it should also give me the number of elements...

Comment: Pandas and NumPy define number of elements in different ways. For Pandas it's the number of rows in a group. For NumPy it seems to consider the fact you have 2 columns in your original dataframe. In general, you should trust Pandas string-based methods where possible.

Comment: Good thing to know. I almost used it without checking.